# Improving temper, good or bad?

Tags: meaning

If something improves your temper, does it do a good thing or a bad one?

I mean, is improving temper good or bad?

Comment: Improving **always** means to *make better*. In this case, what's probably confused you is that *temper* isn't being used to mean *predilection to anger*, but instead simply *mood* or *state of mind*. Always remember that most words have more than one meaning, and if the way a word is used confuses you, you should look it up (in a dictionary) and see if there's another definition which *does* fit the context.

Comment: We might say that someone prone to anger has a _bad temper_ ,so why not make it _better_? True, we rarely speak of _good-tempered_, but a bad one could certainly be improved at least to "even":  _even-tempered_.

Comment: _Good-tempered_ seems normal to me. In the Corpus of Global Web English, it occurs 9 times in British sources, 3 in US, 2 in Australian and one in Irish.

Comment: Correction: that was for _Good tempered_ without a hyphen. With a hyphen it occurs 54 times: GB 19, US 11, AU 7, IE 4, MY 3, and several 2's and 1's.

Comment: And of course *well tempered* steel has undergone the difficult and risky process of *tempering* without shattering, and with the desired effect on both hardness and ductility.

Answer (score 1):

'Temper' is something that can be good or bad. A nasty, grumpy person has a bad temper; a sweet, kind person has a good temper. So 'improving one's temper' makes the temper better. We say things like "he has a temper" to mean a bad temper, but it isn't the original usage.